# Im getting syntax error in my PHP code (api sms sender by android service)

Tags: php, api, syntax, array-merge

Guy i have my .php code extremely well done but i can't understand why i'm getting a syntax error in every line that i have function and array_merge...

Im using the android service application to do the gateway job, and it's supose to send the information from my html page (number message) to the service website so it sends the sms through my phone.

But i can't get this code to work, i'm doing the post with this code:

```
<?php
include "smsGateway.php";
$smsGateway = new SmsGateway($email, $password);

$deviceID = $device;
$number = $number;
$message = $message;

//Please note options is no required and can be left out
$result = $smsGateway->sendMessageToNumber($number, $message, $deviceID, $options);
?>
```

Everything is OK with it, but my main library smsGateway.php is getting a lot of syntax error:

```
<?php

    class SmsGateway {

        static $baseUrl = "https://smsgateway.me";


        function __construct($email,$password) {
            $this->email = $email;
            $this->password = $password;
        }

        function sendMessageToNumber($to, $message, $device, $options=[]) {
            $query = array_merge(['number'=>$to, 'message'=>$message, 'device' => $device], $options);
            return $this->makeRequest('/api/v3/messages/send','POST',$query);
        }

        function sendMessageToManyNumbers ($to, $message, $device, $options=[]) {
            $query = array_merge(['number'=>$to, 'message'=>$message, 'device' => $device], $options);
            return $this->makeRequest('/api/v3/messages/send','POST', $query);
        }

        function sendMessageToContact ($to, $message, $device, $options=[]) {
            $query = array_merge(['contact'=>$to, 'message'=>$message, 'device' => $device], $options);
            return $this->makeRequest('/api/v3/messages/send','POST', $query);
        }

        function sendMessageToManyContacts ($to, $message, $device, $options=[]) {
            $query = array_merge(['contact'=>$to, 'message'=>$message, 'device' => $device], $options);
            return $this->makeRequest('/api/v3/messages/send','POST', $query);
        }

        function sendManyMessages ($data) {
            $query['data'] = $data;
            return $this->makeRequest('/api/v3/messages/send','POST', $query);
        }

        private function makeRequest ($url, $method, $fields=[]) {

            $fields['email'] = $this->email;
            $fields['password'] = $this->password;

            $url = smsGateway::$baseUrl.$url;

            $fieldsString = http_build_query($fields);


            $ch = curl_init();

            if($method == 'POST')
            {
                curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, count($fields));
                curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fieldsString);
            }
            else
            {
                $url .= '?'.$fieldsString;
            }

            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER , false);  // we want headers
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

            $result = curl_exec ($ch);

            $return['response'] = json_decode($result,true);

            if($return['response'] == false)
                $return['response'] = $result;

            $return['status'] = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

            curl_close ($ch);

            return $return;
        }
    }

?>
```

Comment: What version of PHP are you using? `[...]` notation for array literals was added in 5.4. Before that, you have to use `array(...)`.

Comment: i'm using hostinger to host it. using php 5.5. I did this just for that, cause i know in php 5.4 it was already possible.

Comment: i'm getting this error: 
Warning: array_merge(): Argument #2 is not an array in /home/u549063526/public_html/home/smsGateway.php on line 46

the code line is
$query = array_merge(['number'=>$to, 'message'=>$message, 'device' => $device], $options);

Comment: I've reopened the question. You said you were getting a syntax error, but that's not a syntax error. That error means that `$options` isn't an array.

Comment: When you call `sendMessageToNumber`, you're using the variable `$options` but you never initialize it. If you want to use the default value in the function definition, you should leave the argument out entirely.

Answer (score 0):

you should write this

```
$message = ''.$message.'';
```

instead of this

```
$message = $message;
```

Comment: What exactly will this fix?

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand your problem.

I solved it by changing:

```
$options=[]
```

to:

```
$options
```

AND

```
array_merge(['number'=>$to, 'message'=>$message, 'device' => $device], $options);
```

to:

```
array_merge(array('number'=>$to, 'message'=>$message, 'device' => $device), $options);
```

In all lines that these errors occured. It worked.